# Creating a for loop to create multiple objects to add to a graph

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a graph. I'm following a tutorial and this is hard coded way of doing it:

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
          new DataPoint(0, 1),
          new DataPoint(1, 5),
          new DataPoint(2, 3),
          new DataPoint(3, 2),
          new DataPoint(4, 6)
});
graph.addSeries(series);
```

However, I have data coming in from my database which has already been parsed. I'm trying to feed that data to my graph. My way of doing it partially works, the data is displayed on the x-axis and y-axis but the graph itself is not drawn and I'm not sure why.

This is a small snippet of my code:

```
    for(int i =0; i<Profit.length; i++){
Date date = getDate()[i] 
                 series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{
                        new DataPoint(date, Profit[i])


                });


            }

                        graph.addSeries(series);
            System.out.println("GRAPH COMPLETE");
```

I've only shown you the bit that's the problem. It's the loop. I've needed the for loop before `graph.addSeries(series)` so that the data is first collected. But I've found that doing the hard coded way as shown initially works, but the automated way I`m trying to do it, is only half working.

Can someone please advise me on what I need to do?

EDIT:

I've tried to implement the suggested edits but I'm still getting the same result.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyhpu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are reinitializing the **series** every time in the loop.

Try adding it this way.

```
DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[Profit.length];
for(int i =0; i<Profit.length; i++){
    Date date = getDate()[i];
    DataPoint v = new DataPoint(date, Profit[i]);
    //EDIT::
    DataPoint v = new DataPoint(Dates.get(i), Profit[i]);

    values[i] = v;

}

LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(values);
graph.addSeries(series);
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunaltey, this approach only does 50% of the work. I end up getting a solid line on only one of the axis. The line graph does not correspond the anything on the X axis

Comment: Try it with the EDIT way that I have mentioned.

Comment: I tried implementing it the way you suggested, I'm still getting the same issue. I've attached an image in the OP of the result

Comment: What is your expected output? Please share an image for that as well.

Comment: Ideally, just a normal line graph that uses the x and y axis

Answer (score 0):

```
DataPoint[] dataPoints = new DataPoint[Profit.length]; // declare an array of DataPoint objects with the same size as your list
for (int i = 0; i < Profit.length; i++) {
Date date = getDate()[i];
// add new DataPoint object to the array for each of your list entries
 dataPoints[i] = new DataPoint(date, Profit[i]); 
}
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(dataPoints);
```

Currently you are creating a new LineGraphSeries everytime you are running through the for loop.

Comment: Hi, The only issue with doing it this way, is that the graph looks at "datapoints" as values for te x axis, basically, theres a line on the Y axis, there's not a proper line graph, which I suspect has to do with only arugment being passed in as the X axis

Answer (score 0):

You should create list before for loop and inside for loop add elements to list:

```
List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < Profit.length; i++){
    Date date = getDate()[i];
    dataPoints.add(new DataPoint(date, Profit[i]));
}

DataPoint[] pointsArray = new DataPoint[];
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPoints.toArray(pointsArray));

graph.addSeries(series);
System.out.println("GRAPH COMPLETE");
```

Comment: Hi, as mentioned before, the problem with doing it this way is that I'm getting a solid line on only one of the axis. I'm not getting a proper line graph unfortunately. It could because I need to pass in another argument so a proper line graph is drawn

Comment: Hi, what value getDate()[i] returns? It should return x axis value. You can put 'i' instead 'date' in this part: new DataPoint(date, Profit[i])

Comment: Wlodarczyk Unfortunately it's not working. I've posted an image of the result in the OP